# How to pull the first date from another sheet in Excel using?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have an Excel file that contains a `sheet with overview of project task` and a `sheet with summary of that project.`
In the project task sheet, my coworkers have to put in dates for their deadlines.
I need to make an automatic function that pull over the first date in their timeline to the summary sheet. How can I do so?

Here is a picture of the project sheet. 16-dec is the next deadline for example;
[image]

Here is the frontpage (example). The next deadline in a timeline should be here: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like this could work in Excel 365:

```
=IFERROR(TAKE(TOROW(D2:I2,1),,1),"No date")
```

Result:

[image]

In Excel 2021 and above:

```
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK(D2:I2)),D2:I2),"No date")
```

In Excel 2019 and above:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTER(D2:I2,D2:I2<>""),1,1),"No date")
```

Comment: Can I write this line of code, in the front page sheet so it will apear there? Or should I do it in the same sheet where the timeline is?

Comment: I have added the example of a front page

Comment: @Hellihansen you can use this formula in whatever sheet you need. Just refer to sheet where actual data is, for example ='sheet with data'!D2:I2

Comment: It does not work when I do this:
=IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TRUE,NOT(ISBLANK('sheetname'!B24:Z24)),'sheetname'!B24:Z24),"No date")

Comment: i have excel version 2310

Comment: What does "not work" means? Do you get wrong results, do you get error?

Comment: @user11222393 it says there is  a problem with the formula

Comment: @user11222393 In my front page you see the sheetname (project ID) and not the TASK 1, TASK 2, TASK 3 - could that be the problem?

Comment: @Hellihansen it might be that due to regional settings you need to use semicolon separator instead of comma. Try this: =IFERROR(XLOOKUP(TRUE;NOT(ISBLANK('sheetname'!B24:Z24));'sheetname'!B24:Z24);"No date")

Comment: thank you it works. I just have a question, how can I include alle tasks in this formula. So in the front page will appear onlue ONE deadline, that is the next and if two task have a deadline on the same date it will also appear in the frontpage but in the same cell. In the frontpage should each sheet i have only have one line. Hope it makes sense

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly, but it looks like it should be a different question. When posting a new question make sure to post data example AND desired output entered manually for said example

Comment: Okay I will. The formula you made works, but it only shows "no date", even though I have a date in the B24:z24

Comment: Are you sure you refer to sheet with data. It should work as in my example. Also you could try other formulas, just change comma to semicolon

Comment: =IFERROR(TAKE(TOROW(D2:I2,1),,1),"No date")
This one works, but it gives me the number 45246 instead of 16-nov (a date)?

Comment: Excel dates are numbers. 1 is 1 day starting from 1900-01-01. 45246 means that much days since then. Right click on that cell, choose "Format cells". On "Number" tab find "Date" and choose desired format.